# Prepared statement getting error 0

Tags: php, mysqli, errno, prepare

---

Trying to make a prepare statement but for some reason it fails me and i'm getting errno 0 with error (text) being blank. What is causing this? Have been searching the web for a quite while now.

```
<?php 
   $dbh = new mysqli("localhost","root","","honeypot");

   if ($dbh->connect_errno) {
       echo "Connection failed: (" . $dbh->connect_errno . ") " . $dbh->connect_error;  
       die();
   }

   //Prepare
   if (!($stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT tblUsers WHERE UserName = ?"))) {
       echo "Prepare failed: (" . $dbh->connect_errno . ") " . $dbh->connect_error;
   }
?>
```

Comment: Because you aren't executing the query, and you aren't binding anything.... Look at your `//Prepare` if.

Comment: @Darren Why would not executing the query cause `prepare()` to return an error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting `error 0` because you're printing `$dbh->connect_error`, but you didn't have an error making the connection. For everything other than the initial connection you should use `$dbh->error`.

```
echo "Prepare failed: (" . $dbh->errno . ") " . $dbh->error;
```

You're getting an error because your query has a syntax error. It should be:

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3, ... FROM tblUsers WHERE UserName = ?
```

You're missing the list of columns and the `FROM` keyword.